# Flattening edit diffs onto a master record — can I do this more simply or efficiently?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a system that needs to track user edits over time. Due to various constraints, we need to keep the original records pristine and merge the edits down into a single row representing the current state.

I'm essentially aiming for the result of "replaying" the edits, so that edited columns show their most recent edited value and unedited columns show the original.

By simplified example, given a table of original records:

```
books:
book_id | title  | color | year
-------------------------------
1       | First  | blue  | null
2       | Second | green | null
3       | Third  | red   | 1992
```

And a table of edits that have been made to the records where all unchanged values are null:

```
edits:
edit_id | book_id | title | color | year
----------------------------------------
101     | 1       | Uno   | null  | 2003
102     | 1       | Ett   | teal  | null
103     | 2       | null  | null  | 1999
```

I'm producing output like:

```
book_id | title  | color | year
-------------------------------
1       | Ett    | teal  | 2003
2       | Second | green | 1999
3       | Third  | red   | 1992
```

My current implementation works as expected (on PostgreSQL 9.6), but I have the sneaking feeling that I may be missing a simpler or more efficient way to go about it:

```
SELECT
  books.id,
  COALESCE(
    (
      array_agg(edits.title ORDER BY edits.id DESC)
      FILTER (WHERE edits.title IS NOT NULL)
    )[1],
    books.title
  ) as title
  -- [... repeat for other fields ...]
FROM books
LEFT JOIN edits
  ON books.id = edits.book_id
GROUP BY books.id;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I can not see name column in edits table. is it title column ?

Comment: @HarunKARATAŞ Oops — transcription error! Edited to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an aggregate that returns the last non-null value, you could do it like this:

```
select b.book_id, 
       coalesce(last(e.title order by e.edit_id), b.title) as title,
       coalesce(last(e.color order by e.edit_id), b.color) as color,
       coalesce(last(e.year order by e.edit_id), b.year) as year
from books b
  left join edits e on b.book_id = e.book_id
group by b.book_id
order by b.book_id;
```

See [the Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)) for an implementation of the `last()` (and `first()`)  function.

This might be faster as it does not have to keep all values in memory just to pick the last one. It only keeps one value in memory during aggregation.

Comment: Yep, even the SQL version of the `last()` aggregate is faster than using `array_agg()`. Thanks!